# Meteor 1.6 docker container ist not restarting after mup deployment

Tags: meteor, deployment, mup

My deployment with meteor 1.6 and mup is hanging. Deployment works but the docker container ist stuck in restarting mode. (restarting since 1 hour..)

Answer (score 2):

The docker image in the mup.js has to be updated with the following:

```
    docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-binbuild',
    },
```

As meteor 1.6 requires node in version 8.x.x